# Can I buy replacement clips for my soft-close drawer?

Tags: drawers

One of the clips on my soft-close drawers broke--shattered into a dozen pieces beyond repair. Is it possible to buy a replacement without having to buy new slides?

Maybe I'm having trouble with the proper name for these things, but nothing I search seems to yield any results. I've seen them called "locking brackets," but searching for this doesn't give much.

It looks like this:

[image: Orange and blue locking clip]

Comment: the brand name of the drawer is way more important than a picture

Comment: Unfortunately it has no brand name. Looks like I might need to buy new slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTC  soft close drawer slides locking device

[image]
 Available [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01C97YOU8)